# Google cloud speech transcribe 3gp in python

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-speech

I cannot manage to transcribe a simple 3gp audio file with the google cloud speech api. Their example is running fine with audio.raw but when I change it to my file it goes wrong.

Recording is made like this in my android device:

```
 mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
```

I transcribe it like this:

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech

# Instantiates a client
speech_client = speech.Client()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources',
    'phone.3gp')

# Loads the audio into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()
    audio_sample = speech_client.sample(
        content,
        source_uri=None,
        encoding='AMR',
        sample_rate=8000) #LINEAR16

# Detects speech in the audio file
alternatives = speech_client.speech_api.sync_recognize(audio_sample)

for alternative in alternatives:
    print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

Encoding and sample rate is correct but I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transcribe.py", line 26, in <module>
    alternatives = speech_client.speech_api.sync_recognize(audio_sample)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech\_gax.py", line 266, in sync_recognize
    raise ValueError('More than one result or none returned from API.')
ValueError: More than one result or none returned from API.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having the same issue:

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
```

should be

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

The constants are different in the documentation.